# Calling java code from python on windows 8

Tags: java, python, windows

I want to call java code from my python script on a windows 8 machine.

During my research, I have found the following approaches:

- jpype
- pyjnius
- javabridge
- py4j

but I wasn't able to get any of the above to work, so far: Most packages are only available for linux distributions only, or have some other constraints (only 32bit, not working after conda convert from linux to windows, etc.)

Does anyone know an easy solution for calling java code from python on windows 8, 64 bit?

Comment: Do you want to call the java and don't care about it anymore? Or do you need also the output of the java programm to process in your py code later?

Comment: I want to be able to work with java objects within the script.

Answer (score 2):

I have just gotten jpype to work.

See the following blog-post for more information:

[5 ways to call java code from python](http://baojie.org/blog/2014/06/16/call-java-from-python/)